# Expression for $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(k)(-1)^{2k-1}}{k!} x^{k}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I'm looking for an expression by means of which the rational zeta series  $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(k)(-1)^{2k-1}}{k!} x^{k}$$ can be evaluated. Does such an expression exist?

Comment: Isn't $(-1)^{2k-1}=-1$?

Comment: @Gary ah yes haha, you're right. Should've seen that

Comment: It cannot be too nice a function of $x$, because it is conjectured that the values of $\zeta(k)$ for odd $k$ are algebraically independent, while the values of $\zeta(k)$ for even $k$ are rational multiples of $\pi^k$.

Comment: An expression I have found is $$
\sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{\zeta (k)}}{{k!}}x^k }  = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{I_0 (2\sqrt {2tx} ) - 1 - 2tx }}{{\sinh ^2 t}}dt} ,
$$ but there are many others that you can derive.

Comment: @Mindlack There are quite a few series involving odd zeta arguments that evaluate to 'nice' functions or values though! See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series

Comment: @Gary would be great if the integral could be computed!

Comment: @Max Muller: I didn’t know that, actually. But I didn’t really think of the digamma function as “nice”, and most of the other series are for *values* (where, sort of, anything can happen) or the $\zeta(2k)$.

Comment: @Mindlack Fair enough. I suppose niceness is a subjective term as well. (btw: in this case, a polygamma function or something along those lines would be nice enough for me). You may also be interested in the papers by Borwein, Adamchik and Srivastava by the way, I thought it was pretty amazing when I first read about it